# Por que la propiedad tipo dateTime de un objeto tiene valor diferente al que le mando desde el cliente?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

Yo tengo una aplicacion en Angular la cual se conecta a una API de .Net Core 3.1, lo que ocurre es que yo envio una fecha desde la aplicacion de Angular y en el API se traduce a una fecha diferente, ya sea que tiene una hora o dia diferente al que le mande, el problema me esta ocurriendo solo con las propiedades DateTime en los objetos, ya que si es un parametros de un end-point si toma la fecha correcta:

Este es el objeto que envio desde la app en Angular

```
  let appointment: IAppointment = {
          ApptType: this.selectedCompany.EmailType,
          UserId: 0,
          CompanySpecialtyId: this.compSpecialtySelectedId,
          UniqueId: 'null',
          Description: this.appointmentForm.controls["Description"].value,
          EndDate: new Date(selectedDate.getUTCFullYear(), selectedDate.getUTCMonth(), selectedDate.getUTCDate(), 0, selectedHour.EndMinutes).toISOString(),
          StartDate: startDate.toISOString(),
          Id: 0,
          Status: AppointmentStatus.WAITING,
          Title: `${selectedSpecialtyDesc}${currentUser.Name}`
        };
```

El campo EndDate y StartDate si no los convierto a toISOString el api me manda un error de que no se puede convertir la fecha

Este es el error

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime. Path:
> $.StartDate | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 149.

Este es el objeto en la solicitud

```
{
   "ApptType":0,
   "UserId":0,
   "CompanySpecialtyId":1,
   "UniqueId":"null",
   "Description":"",
   "EndDate":"2022-09-05T11:20:00.000Z",
   "StartDate":"2022-09-05T10:50:00.000Z",
   "Id":0,
   "Status":2,
   "Title":"Prueba 30 min | ISAAC HERRERA"
}
```

Y al api me llega este valor
**EndDate**: 05/09/2022 11:20:00 a. m. |
**StartDate**: 05/09/2022 10:50:00 a. m.

Y asi me llegan cuando los recibo como parametros
**StartDate**: 05/09/2022 04:50:00 a. m. |
**EndDate**: 05/09/2022 05:20:00 a. m.

Agradeceria mucho si me pueden ayudar con esto

Comment: Esto se produce por los UTC offset, tu envías con UTC-0 (eso lo que quiere decir la Z al final de la fecha). Cuando lo recibe la api lo transforma a hora local. Debes o enviar la fecha en hora local o en la API setear el datetime que será en hora UTC

Comment: @Yussef gracias por responder, una pregunta como podria hacer la segunda opcion que me das, los de cambiar el dateTime a UTC?

Comment: Sabes volví a leer y me enredé, puedes explicar lo último que pusiste en tu mensaje original. Es decir, tu tienes un input Fecha1, luego la conviertes con toISOString a una Fecha2 y luego en la API te llega una Fecha3?? si es así da un ejemplo de esas fechas

Comment: @Yussef yo creo un objeto Date en angular, el me genera la fecha correcta, despues lo convierto a toISOString, el cual me genera otro tipo de fecha pero en string, y cuando llega al API no obtengo la fecha correcta sino otra que o esta mas adelantada o atrasada

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema con el UTC offset, puedes leer más aqui [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), en general no es malo trabajar siempre en UTC-0 en todas las fechas, sobre todo cuando:

- Tu aplicación se ejecuta en varias regiones distintas y con diferentes horarios
- Tu aplicación se ejecuta en una región distinta a tu servidor
- Tu sistema realiza cálculos con diferencias de tiempo (ejemplo: productos vendidos por hora) y en tu país realizan cambios de hora.

Lo malo, es que siempre para presentar las fechas deberás convertirlas a hora local (según el cliente), para no confundir.

Por otro lado, y esto en mi opinión personal, hay casos que no merecen la pena enredarse con el tema de UTC offset. Por ejemplo, la típica aplicación interna de una empresa, donde necesitas el datetime de reloj sin importar si hay cambios de horario o no.

Entonces si en tu caso te interesa guardar en UTC-0 ya lo tendrías hecho, ahora solo deberías preocuparte de que cuando se muestran las fechas se hagan en hora local.

Si sigues el otro camino, el de que no te importe el UTC, puedes enviar la fecha local simplemente. Para esto existen variar librerías en javascript que permiten formatear los Date (porque javascript es muy malo para manejar fechas).

Te dejo un pequeño código que convierte un Date a formato iso, sin cambiar la hora. (posiblemente esto se puede hacer mucho mejor)

```
function GetFechaString(d) {
    return d.getFullYear() + "-" +
        ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
        ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "T" +
        ("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
        ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" +
        ("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + "Z";
}
```

Es decir, ocupas esta función en vez de toISOString

Otra opción es volver a cambiar la fecha desde C# con la función ToLocalTime que tienen los DateTime, algo así:

```
obj.EndDate.ToLocalTime()
```